# Combine two text field validation functions

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

How would I combine these functions to where if one is false `setregisterButton(enabled)` is also false or `setregisterButton(enabled: false)`. It works after I put it in the password matching method but if I decide to change the original password, I want the button to deselect again.

Also this is off topic but is there a way to check if email is already used in Firebase?

```
@IBAction func validatePasswordField() {
    validatePasswordTextFieldWithText(password: passwordField.text)
}

func validatePasswordTextFieldWithText(password: String?) {
    guard let password2 = password else {
        passwordField.errorMessage = nil
        return
    }

    if password2.isEmpty {
        passwordField.errorMessage = nil
    } else if !validatePassword(password2: password2) {
        passwordField.errorMessage = NSLocalizedString(
            "Password must be 8 characters long with an uppercase and 
 number",
            tableName: "SkyFloatingLabelTextField",
            comment: " "
        )
    } else {
        passwordField.errorMessage = nil
    }
}

func validatePassword(password2:String?) -> Bool {
    // at least one uppercase,
    // at least one digit
    // at least one lowercase
    // 8 characters total
    let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "(?=.*[A- 
  Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}")
    return passwordTest.evaluate(with: password2)
}

@IBAction func validatePasswordMatch() {
    validatePasswordMatchWithText(password: RetypepasswordField.text)
}

func validatePasswordMatchWithText(password: String?) {
    guard let password4 = password else {
        RetypepasswordField.errorMessage = nil
        return
    }

    if password4.isEmpty {
        RetypepasswordField.errorMessage = nil
    } else if !validatePasswordMatch(password3: password4) {
        RetypepasswordField.errorMessage = NSLocalizedString(
            "Passwords do not match",
            tableName: "SkyFloatingLabelTextField",
            comment: " "
        )
    } else {
        RetypepasswordField.errorMessage = nil; 
        setregisterButton(enabled: true)
    }
}

func validatePasswordMatch(password3:String?) -> Bool {
    let pass = passwordField.text
    let pass2 = RetypepasswordField.text

    let actualPassword = (pass == pass2)
    return actualPassword
}
```

Comment: `setregisterButton` is called once only, What exactly do you want, I still don't get it. Can you pls explain a little bit more.

Comment: Pretty much i want the button to be true after the two conditions are met. So after it is determined the two passwords match and the password has 8 characters.